# How to merge two objects at identical face?

Tags: objects, 3d-view, edit-mode

I have two objects which have each an identical (mirrored) face. Now I'd like to orient the two objects such that those two face match. If I just use the merge tool, the remaining parts of the objects stay exactly where they are, but I don't want the objects themselves to change, I basically just want to "glue" the two objects together at a certain face. Is there an easy way to do so?

In the following I provided an example file with two objects that have one common mirrored face as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of a specific function that would align and merge at the same time so doing it manually is the best option that I know of.

First, to align the two objects select them both and in the properties panel (N) you will see rotation values, right click on them and click "Copy All To Selected" you should get something like this:

[image]

Then, under the viewport you should see a magnet button, enable the magnet and then set the snapping to vertex:

[image]

Select your "Plane" object and then press G after moving it in the general direction of the other object (its best to view it from the angle of the other face) the object will align to the vertex on the other shape:

[image]

After that switch into edit mode and keep the whole "Plane" object selected, then align one corner to the other and it will be perfectly aligned:

[image]

Finally, exit edit mode, select both objects and hit Ctrl+J, now go back into edit mode and you can edit both objects, simply merge the vertices together (This will be difficult but not impossible just click around the vertices and it will select both sides) and delete the inner face to clean up and you're done! :) Final result:

[image]

I would just like to say that although this method works it is completely unnecessary as these objects should've been created together in the first place, from what I saw there was no need for these to be separate objects, in future create objects in edit mode or extrude instead of creating new separate objects it will save you from going to all this effort and will be much faster too. Happy Blending :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer so far! The snapping already helps a lot, but regarding the rotation I am interested in a more general case. Here you used the fact that I duplicated the original face and then added further vertices etc so that way one could just match the rotation angles of the two objects in order to get them aligned, but I'm also interestied in the case where this is not possible (assume we applied the rotation in my file before doing anything else). Is it for instance possible to get the needed rotation angles from the normals of the corresponding faces?

Comment: (Regarding modelling: I know for general modelling this is probably not what we want to do, in my case I have some geometric constructions in mind where you'd still need to do something like that. As an example: Take two cubes. Cut of one corner of each cube such that you get a triangular face, than "glue" the two cubes together. I thought my approach from above would be the easiest for things like that.)

Comment: @flawr it is possible in vanilla Blender with snapping as well, one way is [snapping with parenting to empty](https://imgur.com/a/pko96) and snapping empty. All other steps are generally the same.

Comment: @MrZak I'm trying to replicate your solution: Is it correct that the empty should snap to a certain center point of that face? So far I only managed to let it snap to the face, but at some arbitrary point.

Comment: @flawr, empty should be snapped to the face and its rotation be aligned with that face but at any point of the face, so it doesn't matter to the center or not

Comment: one more question: how do you rotate around a *local axis* (that is what I read from the statusbar in your film)? EDIT: found it: `r z z` (or replacing `z` with any of the other axes)

Comment: @flawr yes, transform orientations other than Global (default one) are accessible via pressing axis name twice (so if Local is selected as orientation then R X X is along local X, if Normal - then R X X is along normal X etc).

Answer (score 2):

With the Mesh-Align-Plus Addon its easy to align.

Download the addon [here](https://github.com/egtwobits/mesh-align-plus)

Install the addon

You can find the addon is in tool shelf -> Mesh -> In the Quick Align Planes

In the edit mode select 3 verts and click on Grab Destination of 1st object

Select the 2nd object in edit mode select 3 verts and click the object

The align is perfect.

[image]